# Trying use a prompt to parse and find specific keys in nested JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-slides, nested-json

I'm attempting to parse a dynamic complex nested JSON file, where the result would be finding the specific key in an array. Here's a snippet of non-working code:

```
if (input == 'Special Weather Statement') {
        var url = "https://api.weather.gov/alerts?zone=AKZ201";
        var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage();
        var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        var content = res.getContentText();
        var json = JSON.parse(content);
        Logger.log(json);

        
        var event = json['features']['properties']['event'];
        if (event == 'Special Weather Statement') {
          var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 20, 259, 420, 60);
          var textRange = shape.getText();
          var description = json['features'][0]['properties']['description'];
          var description = description.replaceAll('\n',' ');
            textRange.setText(description);
            textRange.getTextStyle().setFontSize(17).setForegroundColor('#ffffff').setFontFamily("Libre Franklin");
```

The problem lies in the "var event" line. If I were to do:

```
var event = json['features'][0]['properties']['event'];
```

The code only reads the first block of the array, where I want to fully search the JSON, find where there are arrays that have 'event' = 'Special Weather Statement' (or whatever the event input is).

After, I would want to sort the final output as having the most recent event from the 'sent' key in that specific JSON.

Here's a sample of the JSON structure:

```
{
    "@context": [
        "https://geojson.org/geojson-ld/geojson-context.jsonld",
        {
            "@version": "1.1",
            "wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#",
            "@vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#"
        }
    ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.1ca69af04faf0efdc58521c0b1b11b10fc0a6cd0.001.1",
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": null,
            "properties": {
                "@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.1ca69af04faf0efdc58521c0b1b11b10fc0a6cd0.001.1",
                "@type": "wx:Alert",
                "id": "urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.1ca69af04faf0efdc58521c0b1b11b10fc0a6cd0.001.1",
                "areaDesc": "Western Arctic Coast; Northern Arctic Coast",
                "geocode": {
                    "SAME": [
                        "002185"
                    ],
                    "UGC": [
                        "AKZ201",
                        "AKZ202"
                    ]
                },
                "affectedZones": [
                    "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/AKZ201",
                    "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/AKZ202"
                ],
                "references": [],
                "sent": "2022-10-09T14:23:00-08:00",
                "effective": "2022-10-09T14:23:00-08:00",
                "onset": "2022-10-09T14:23:00-08:00",
                "expires": "2022-10-10T05:00:00-08:00",
                "ends": null,
                "status": "Actual",
                "messageType": "Alert",
                "category": "Met",
                "severity": "Moderate",
                "certainty": "Observed",
                "urgency": "Expected",
                "event": "Special Weather Statement",
                "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov",
                "senderName": "NWS Fairbanks AK",
                "headline": "Special Weather Statement issued October 9 at 2:23PM AKDT by NWS Fairbanks AK",
                "description": "West winds of 25 to 35 mph blowing over a large fetch of open\nwater over the Arctic Ocean and Chukchi Sea will cause elevated\nwater levels potentially 1 to 3 feet above the highest high tide\nand elevated surf along the Arctic Coast from Tuesday through\nThursday. This will likely lead to beach erosion along the Arctic\nCoast.",
                "instruction": null,
                "response": "Execute",
                "parameters": {
                    "AWIPSidentifier": [
                        "SPSNSB"
                    ],
                    "WMOidentifier": [
                        "WWAK81 PAFG 092223"
                    ],
                    "NWSheadline": [
                        "Elevated Surf Possible Tuesday Through Thursday"
                    ],
                    "BLOCKCHANNEL": [
                        "EAS",
                        "NWEM",
                        "CMAS"
                    ],
                    "EAS-ORG": [
                        "WXR"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.fb007fa8f54048b448cba44f41ac214a0aae3bb0.001.1",
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": null,
            "properties": {
                "@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.fb007fa8f54048b448cba44f41ac214a0aae3bb0.001.1",
                "@type": "wx:Alert",
                "id": "urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.fb007fa8f54048b448cba44f41ac214a0aae3bb0.001.1",
                "areaDesc": "Western Arctic Coast; Northern Arctic Coast; Central Beaufort Sea Coast; Eastern Beaufort Sea Coast",
                "geocode": {
                    "SAME": [
                        "002185"
                    ],
                    "UGC": [
                        "AKZ201",
                        "AKZ202",
                        "AKZ203",
                        "AKZ204"
                    ]
                },
                "affectedZones": [
                    "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/AKZ201",
                    "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/AKZ202",
                    "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/AKZ203",
                    "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/AKZ204"
                ],
                "references": [],
                "sent": "2022-10-09T06:42:00-08:00",
                "effective": "2022-10-09T06:42:00-08:00",
                "onset": "2022-10-09T06:42:00-08:00",
                "expires": "2022-10-09T16:45:00-08:00",
                "ends": null,
                "status": "Actual",
                "messageType": "Alert",
                "category": "Met",
                "severity": "Moderate",
                "certainty": "Observed",
                "urgency": "Expected",
                "event": "Special Weather Statement",
                "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov",
                "senderName": "NWS Fairbanks AK",
                "headline": "Special Weather Statement issued October 9 at 6:42AM AKDT by NWS Fairbanks AK",
                "description": "West winds of 25 to 35 mph blowing over a 600 NM fetch of open\nwater over the Arctic Ocean and Chukchi Sea will cause elevated\nwater levels and elevated surf along the Arctic Coast from Monday\nnight through Thursday. This will likely lead to beach erosion\nalong the Arctic Coast Monday night through Thursday.",
                "instruction": null,
                "response": "Execute",
                "parameters": {
                    "AWIPSidentifier": [
                        "SPSNSB"
                    ],
                    "WMOidentifier": [
                        "WWAK81 PAFG 091442"
                    ],
                    "NWSheadline": [
                        "Elevated Surf Possible Monday Night Through Thursday"
                    ],
                    "BLOCKCHANNEL": [
                        "EAS",
                        "NWEM",
                        "CMAS"
                    ],
                    "EAS-ORG": [
                        "WXR"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

I would appreciate any help or input, thanks!

Comment: Can you post sample json structure

Comment: @SivaRmK: Just added, sorry!

Comment: You need to iterate the array `json.features`, rather than accessing the 0 index directly

Comment: @GalAbra How would I go about doing this from a URL? I'm very inexperienced, but I tried Googling some examples, but it wasn't completely clear.

Comment: Hey, welcome :) So what do you mean by url?

Comment: @GalAbra I guess I mean how would it explicitly extract the key if there are multiples of the same key-value pairing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to order the features array, and after getting the first element of the ordered array:

###### Sample:

```js
  var url = "https://api.weather.gov/alerts?zone=AKZ201";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  const orderedEvents = json.features.sort((a,b)=>{
    return new Date(b.properties.sent).getTime() - new Date(a.properties.sent).getTime()
  })
  console.log(orderedEvents[0].properties.event)
```

###### Documentation

- Ref: [Method to compare the Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Comment: Thanks for your help! One question for you: How would I go from this final product to creating a prompt to have the user input the event? For instance, I want the user to input the event name, and have the code search the array and pull the event with the same name as the user inputs, as well as pulling the most recent event.

Comment: This is the topic for another question, if you consider my answer has helped you, please upvote/accept it!

Comment: I posted another question if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it!